# Setup websocket nginx proxy to node.js using ssl from certbot

Tags: nginx, websocket, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, certbot

I want to us ssl websockets (wss://) with my node application that is using the `ws` npm module. On top of it I want to use the ssl that I set up with nginx from certbot.

I have the node websocket listening on port 8080, and while I can connect directly to that, since the site is being served via ssl, that causes an error to be thrown since it isn't encrypted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the client side javascript, you can route your calls to wss://examplesite.com/websocket

- In the nginx config, set up the connection to close when header is set to ''.
- create an upstream to your websocket port
- add the /websocket location

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

upstream websocket {
   server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
    server_name examplesite.com;
    location /websocket {
            proxy_pass http://websocket;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

# after this is just an example of the rest of the nginx config for a node server on 8675
# that has a static build directory
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8675;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    location ~ \.(gif|jpg|png|js|txt|html|mp3|css|woff2)$ {
        root /root/examplesite.com/build/;
        expires 30d;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/examplesite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/examplesite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/wscat to test out your local ws://...:8080 and your wss://.../websocket connection

Comment: what's the directory of the websocket log files?